# A Core-Data Relashionship not working after stopping the app

Tags: ios4, core-data, ios5, ios-simulator, relationship

I have had one issue with Core Data and Relationship. Since this has kept me without a solution for a while and has at the same time been easy to locate I have made a tiny sample application to reproduce the problem.
Under XCode I created a barebone Window-based application, checking "Use Core Data for storage".
I called this application "CDR" for Core-Data-Relationship.
I then added a subclass of UIViewController called CDR_ViewController; as I usually do.
Here is the relevant code that I added :
First in CDR_ViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate_Shared.h"

@interface CDR_ViewController : UIViewController {
UILabel *cdrLabel;
NSManagedObject *currentItem;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *cdrLabel;

-(IBAction) handleButtonClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then in CDR_ViewController.m the viewDidLoad method is as follow :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSFetchRequest *request;
NSError *error;

AppDelegate_Shared *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CDR_Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

error=nil;
NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release];
if (count!=0) {
    request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CDR_Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
    error=nil;
    NSArray *objects=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
    [request release];
    currentItem=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
    return;
}

NSManagedObject *newItemOne,*newItemTwo,*newItemThree;

request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CDR_Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

newItemOne=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDR_Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
newItemTwo=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDR_Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
newItemThree=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CDR_Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newItemOne setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] forKey:@"Value"];
[newItemTwo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2] forKey:@"Value"];
[newItemThree setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] forKey:@"Value"];

[newItemOne setValue:newItemThree forKey:@"Previous"];
[newItemOne setValue:newItemTwo forKey:@"Next"];
[newItemTwo setValue:newItemOne forKey:@"Previous"];
[newItemTwo setValue:newItemThree forKey:@"Next"];
[newItemThree setValue:newItemTwo forKey:@"Previous"];
[newItemThree setValue:newItemOne forKey:@"Next"];

error=nil;
[context save:&error];
[request release];
currentItem=newItemOne;
}
```

And the viewWillAppear method is as follow :

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
cdrLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[currentItem valueForKey:@"Value"]];
}
```

Finally the handleButtonClick method is as follow :

```
-(IBAction) handleButtonClick:(id)sender
{
if (((UIButton*)sender).tag==101) {// Previous item.
    currentItem=[currentItem valueForKey:@"Previous"];
} else /*(((UIButton*)sender).tag==102)*/ {// Next item.
    currentItem=[currentItem valueForKey:@"Next"];
}
cdrLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[currentItem valueForKey:@"Value"]];
}
```

The CDR_ViewController.xib contains one Label and two buttons.

This code works fine for start, meaning just after I compile the app and reset the contents of the iPhone simulator.
I can then cycle the contents of the label : 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3 ---etc… and backward with the buttons. 
As soon as I terminate the application using Command-Q. When I want to start it again, it crashes on :

```
currentItem=[currentItem valueForKey:@"Previous"];
```

or:

```
currentItem=[currentItem valueForKey:@"Next"];
```

inside the handleButtonClick method.
And it is the same when I put the app on my iPod touch.

Can anyone see in my code anything that could explain this behavior?

Comment: How do I accept an answer? I would like to accept a good number of them actually. I will take a look at the link you mention.

Answer (score 0):

If you terminate an app in the simulator by stopping it, a opposed to clicking the home button in the simulator or otherwise, then the program is sent a SIGKILL message which immediately stop it running. Your application delegate methods (will terminate, will enter background etc) will not be called.

In all likelihood this will have meant that your managed object context has not been saved, so when re-running the app the object graph cannot be restored properly. In your sample app, add another button which saves the context. If you click this button, then terminate your app, does that solve the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I run on the device, where I have to use the home button to close, the problem is still the same. And as you can see in my code I have put a [context save:&error]; instruction in order to save. One more remark is that when I launch the application, even after a Command-Q the first value pops up correctly, it is only when I push one of the 2 buttons that it crashes.

Comment: Can you post more details of how it crashes? Do you get a readout in the debugger?